# Bots vulnerability of a web page not using regular form submission but only web service calls from jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, bots

I have an ASP.Net page called Issue.aspx that has an empty code-behind since there is no regular form submission. All interaction with the back end occurs through ajax-enabled web service calls that get called using jquery ajax method.

The full code for this page is as given below.

**Question**

Does not using regular form submission/processing offer protection against BOTS?

Even if a BOT submits a POST request for this page, its not going to do anything since there is no C# in code-behind; it will simply post without doing anything in the back-end. What I am not sure is whether a BOT can discover the web service call `https://www.abc123.com/issueservice/save` from JavaScript code in page and if it does, then how will it spam this service method.

***Making web service (ASMX) method BOT proof, but may be this is an overkill and not required***

I could add an extra parameter `firstName` to the web service method being called, and inside the web service C# code check if firstName is an empty string. If the BOT does discover and call this web service method, then it will send a non-empty value for firstName and I can simply return from web service method without executing any processing code.

*Page markup and code for Issue.aspx (code-behind is empty)*

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Issue.aspx.cs" Inherits="Issue" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
      <title>Issue Logging</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <h1>
         Log your Issue below
         <h1>
         <div>
            Name : 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtIssueName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </div>
         <div>
            Description : 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtIssueDescription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         </div>
         <div>
            Severity : 
            <asp:DropDownList id="ddlType" runat="server">
               <asp:ListItem Text="Low" Value="l"></asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Text="Medium" Value="m"></asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Text="High" Value="h"></asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Text="Very High" Value="v"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
         </div>
         <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveIssue" UseSubmitBehavior="false" onClientClick="saveIssue(); return false; runat="server" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
         </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            function saveIssue() {

            var data= {};

            data.issueName = document.getElementbyId("<%=txtIssueName.ClientID%>").value;
            data.issueDescription =  document.getElementbyId("<%=txtIssueDescription.ClientID%>").value;
            data.issueSeverity = document.getElementById("<%=ddlType.ClientID %>").value;

            if(!data.issueName || !data.issueDescription || !data.issueSeverity) {
            alert("Please input all information for the Issue being submitted!");
            return;
            }
             var url = "https://www.abc123.com/issueservice/save";
                       $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: url,
                           data: JSON.stringify(data),
                           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                           dataType: "json",
                           success: function (r) {
                               onSuccess(r);
                           },
                           error: function (r) {
                               if (onError) {
                                   onError(r);
                               } else {
                                   onErrorStandard(r);
                               }
                           }
                       });
            }

         </script>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is that mysterious "the bot" thing? Are you concerned about regular crawlers or someone making specialized script that automates your site?

Comment: I am concerned that some automated tool would submit an Issue which will then get saved to the database. My understanding about BOT is that it uses an automated tool to submit web pages with false data.

Comment: For that you need to add some sort of protection to your webservice. Your page is just another client for it, and is not the only route to it. Perhaps users have to authenticate, maybe? Or you only accept requests with the origin of your web page? BTW an attack doesn't have to be automated, it could be done by a human using POSTMAN or similar tool just the same. Your firstname parameter idea is pretty crude, anyone looking at your JS and hoping to design an attack will soon discover this technique and crack it.

Comment: It generally takes less that 10-15 minutes to build "some automated tool" for any particular site by looking at HTTP traffic (if you never used tool like Fiddler it is good time to try). This is especially the case if it is automating for self (if site requires some form of authentication). So you really need to clarify what exactly you want to protect against. So far is way too broad for SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I want to protect against the following scenario. A real user is not submitting data i.e. Issue Name, Description and Severity, but a BOT is submitting it. Instead a BOT is submitting this data and the web service method will go ahead and save this issue in database. End result is that I have an issue logged that is not a real issue, but a spam issue.

Comment: @ADyson, I am checking in my web service method whether the user is authenticated and only then going ahead with regular processing. May be that is enough protection against a BOT?

Comment: I hope you are using authentication at web service end. Are you?

Comment: @PrateekPandey, Yes, I am.

Comment: What web service framework (Web API, WCF, ASMX or some other) are you using?

Comment: @PrateekPandey, ASMX.

Comment: Authentication is good, you should also think about throttling or usage limits, to guard against denial of service attacks and that kind of thing. Securing and hardening a web service / API is a broad topic.

Comment: @ADyson, Thanks. So, it seems, I need to add some checks in my C# code of web service method to minimize bot attacks. Yes, I agree its not very specific but a vast topic when it comes to preventing bots in my scenario.